# The second number in his size

Tags: c#

Well its not hard and i did it but i dont know how to find it position.
I know to find the position in CASE1 and CASE2 but not in CASE3.
Any help?

```
        int serial = 1, num, max, max2, i = 2,n;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of numbers");
        n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        /*case 1 */
        max = num;
        max2 = num;
        for (; i <= n; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter num");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             /* case 3 */
            if (num > max)
            {
                max2 = max;
                max = num;
                serial = i;
            }
              /* case 2 */
            else if (num > max2)
            {
                max2 = num;
                serial = i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: That  should work as expected.

Comment: I need to find the second largest number out of N numbers(the user type how much number he will enter)
i also need to find the position of the second number in the list, i know how to do it in CASE 1 and 2 but don't know if its working in case 3(VS stopped working)

Comment: The user enter N numbers(fisrt he enter the number of numbers and then the numbers)
from all those numbers i need to find the second largest(if i have 5 2 4, 4 is the second)
and find is position in the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let use one more variable to store the position of the maximum number also. In the below `serial2` is the result of your problem.

```
int serial = 1, serial2 = 1, num, max, max2, i = 2,n;
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of numbers");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
/*case 1 */
max = num;
max2 = num;
for (; i <= n; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter num");
    num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     /* case 3 */
    if (num > max)
    {
        max2 = max;
        max = num;
        serial2 = serial;
        serial = i;
    }
      /* case 2 */
    else if (num > max2)
    {
        max2 = num;
        serial2 = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after - you just weren't updating your second largest index when your entered number replaced the largest number:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter number of numbers");
int numberOfNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int? largestNumber = null;
int? secondLargestNumber = null;
int? indexOfLargestNumber = null;
int? indexOfSecondLargestNumber = null;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNumbers; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter number");
    int inputNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (largestNumber == null || inputNumber > largestNumber)
    { 

        secondLargestNumber = largestNumber;
        largestNumber = inputNumber;

        indexOfSecondLargestNumber = indexOfLargestNumber;
        indexOfLargestNumber = i;

    }
    else if (secondLargestNumber == null || inputNumber > secondLargestNumber)
    {
        secondLargestNumber = inputNumber;
        indexOfSecondLargestNumber = i;
    }
}

/*because you started i=1 rather than i=0 as I've done, incrememting the indexes by 1*/
indexOfSecondLargestNumber++;
indexOfLargestNumber++;

Console.WriteLine("The {0} number entered ({1}) was the second largest.",indexOfSecondLargestNumber,secondLargestNumber);
```